# Passport will expire in 4 months. Will UAE grant a visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai

I am planning to visit Dubai at the end of December 2015. I am an Indian citizen and my passport expires at the end of April 2016.

I applied for a visa, will it be granted ?

Answer (score 2):

The United Arab Emirates requires Indian passports be valid for at least 3 months from the date of entry for stays of less than 3 months, and at least 6 months for stays of 3-6 months.

Given you have 4 months remaining, presuming you plan to stay in the UAE for less than 3 months you are fine.

However if you are transiting any other countries on the way to/from Dubai keep in mind that they may require a longer validity (a minimum of 6 months is common to enter a country, although most do not have such restrictions if you are just in air-side transit).